# Iterate thru a HashMap and start a Thread for every Different Value

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap

I need to write code that processes a HashMap (with two different classes being its key and value) and creates a thread for each of its items. To execute a thread, the code will take an entry from that HashMap and check if there is a thread with the same value. If it exists, it will skip this entry until that thread finishes executing. The code must go through this HashMap until it is empty, without breaking the condition I mentioned above. However, I am having trouble implementing this logic.

I created an Executor Service based on the number of processors and a list of values (from HashMap) that are being executed. But I don't know how I can remove the value from this list after the thread has finished running.

Here's my unfinished and untested code:

```
    int threads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    List<Future<Boolean>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    List<UnidadeOrganizacionalView> dealershipsBeingExecuted = new ArrayList<>();
    dealershipsBeingExecuted = Collections.synchronizedList(dealershipsBeingExecuted);

    Iterator<Map.Entry<NotaResumoView, UnidadeOrganizacionalView>> it =
            preparedNfs.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<NotaResumoView, UnidadeOrganizacionalView> pair = it.next();
        if (dealershipsBeingExecuted.contains(pair.getValue())){
            it.next();
        }
        dealershipsBeingExecuted.add(pair.getValue());
        futures.add(executor.submit(
                new ConfirmNfeProcessor(Integration, pair.getKey(), pair.getValue())););
        it.remove();
    }
```

Comment: Don't call the objects that you submit to an `ExecutorService` "threads." Those objects are _tasks_. The ExecutorService creates its own threads, which it uses to perform the tasks that you submit to it.

Comment: Instead of having a `List<Future<Boolean>> futures` and a `List<UnidadeOrganizacionalView> dealershipsBeingExecuted`, you should have a single `Map<UnidadeOrganizacionalView,Future<Boolean>> pending` that allows you to get the already existing task and wait for its completion as required.

Comment: Solomon Slow, thanks for correcting me, I have this habit of calling tasks threads, probably caused by my lack of knowledge in relation to Java 8 multitasking.

Comment: Unrelated: you deleted that other question before I finished typing my comment. Thing is: breaking down your complex business code into a SMALL example is exactly how you normally debug such problems, independent of asking about them here or not. That is the essence: you start with a minimalistic thing, and then you slowly add a bit more, up to the point when you "hit" your error. And if that doesnt alone give you an idea what is wrong, then you have something you can share here. Anything else is a waste of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this, is to use `CompletableFuture`, which allows you to chain dependent actions, like submitting another job, when the asynchronous evaluation has been completed.

E.g.

```
Map<UnidadeOrganizacionalView, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> pending = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<NotaResumoView, UnidadeOrganizacionalView> e: preparedNfs.entrySet()) {
    UnidadeOrganizacionalView value = e.getValue();
    ConfirmNfeProcessor p = new ConfirmNfeProcessor(Integration, e.getKey(), value);
    pending.compute(value, (key,future) -> future == null?
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(p, executor):
        future.thenApplyAsync(b -> p.get(), executor));
}

// if you want to wait for the completion of all job:
CompletableFuture.allOf(pending.values().toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0])).join();
```

It uses a `Map<UnidadeOrganizacionalView, CompletableFuture<Boolean>>` to remember the already submitted jobs.

This is used within the `compute` method. It will call `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(p, executor)` when there was no previous job associated with the value, to create a new one and remember it. Otherwise, it will create a new job via `thenApplyAsync`, that will be started when the previous one has been completed, and remembers this new job.

This assumes that it is possible to change the class `ConfirmNfeProcessor` from implementing `Callable<Boolean>` to implementing `Supplier<Boolean>`. The main difference, besides the name of the relevant method, is that a `Supplier` can not throw checked exceptions. If such a change is not possible, you need adapter code.

One possibility would be:

```
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> callAsync(Callable<R> callable, Executor e) {
    CompletableFuture<R> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        try { cf.complete(callable.call()); }
        catch(Throwable ex) { cf.completeExceptionally(ex); }
    }, e);
    return cf;
}
public static <R> CompletableFuture<R> thenCallAsync(
                  CompletableFuture<?> f, Callable<R> callable, Executor e) {
    CompletableFuture<R> cf = new CompletableFuture<>();
    f.whenCompleteAsync((value, t) -> {
        if(t != null) cf.completeExceptionally(t);
        else try { cf.complete(callable.call()); }
        catch(Throwable ex) { cf.completeExceptionally(ex); }
    }, e);
    return cf;
}
```

to be used like

```
Map<UnidadeOrganizacionalView, CompletableFuture<Boolean>> pending = new HashMap<>();

for(Map.Entry<NotaResumoView, UnidadeOrganizacionalView> e: preparedNfs.entrySet()) {
    UnidadeOrganizacionalView value = e.getValue();
    ConfirmNfeProcessor p = new ConfirmNfeProcessor(Integration, e.getKey(), value);
    pending.compute(value, (key,future) -> future == null?
        callAsync(p, executor): thenCallAsync(future, p, executor));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't remember about CompletableFuture and didn't even think about using it in association with the value. This helped alot.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a bit of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) there. It looks to me as if your actual requirement is to ensure that no two threads run `ConfirmNfeProcessor` tasks for the same dealership at the same time, is that right?

Instead of having one fixed thread pool with N worker threads, I would use an array of N thread "pools" that have one thread each. Then, for each `pair` in the map, I would use `pair.getValue().hashCode()` to choose which one of the N executors should perform the task.

Every `pair` that has the same value ("value" == "dealership", right?) will be submitted to the same executor, and since each executor is single-threaded, it will be guaranteed to never perform two tasks for the same dealership at the same time.